# How to get access token for further API calls in next-auth when you use personal server as provider in NextJs with TS?

Tags: typescript, next.js, access-token, next-auth

Above I use my custom provider and when I try to console log the session object, it still shows only user id and name

```
callbacks: {
        async jwt({token, user}){
            return {...token, ...user}
        },
        async session({session, token, user}){
            session.user = token as any;
            return session;
        }
    }
```

I want a solution with new and updated technologies